# Why a file download fast via Ethernet / from Wifi but slow upload to another pc?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

I try to transfer a network video in windows 10 but something curious comes up:

I can download via Ethernet cable from the pc with Wifi at an average speed of 6 MBps but when trying to upload a file to PC with Wifi the maximum speed is 1MBps. Both PCs are connected to the same router. What could it be?

[image: chart of various transfer speeds]

Comment: Where do you write the video to (SD-card, HDD,...)? what tool/command do you use for the operations?

Comment: Please use [iPerf](http://iperf.fr) to test the performance of the link between your computers. This is a more objective test than transferring files. It will help you troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: Your question says MBps but your chart says Mbps. Also, are you really saying that wired on both ends wasn't the fastest? Are you sure about that? How exactly did you test?

Answer (score 0):

Your question and table makes no sense.  Are you saying that you get more bandwidth when you transfer a file via a wired connection and less bandwidth when you transfer via a wireless connection?

PC1 -------wired-------- PC2
6MB/s or 48Mbps

PC1 (((  Wireless ))) PC2
1MB/s or 8Mbps

If so, 48Mbps on a 10/100 link is very respectable for TCP and 8Mbps is very respectable on a mixed-mode 802.11bg wireless network.

As you can see, these are all educated guesses because you did not provide any information.  Your table makes no sense, please consider revising.  Why are the Arrows pointed in both directions.  Please provide the make and model of your router.  Please provide the direction of your traffic.  Please provide the size of the file you are transferring and mechanism you are using to transfer that file.  I'm guessing it's Windows Copy, but you've got to clarify that.